# Changing HTML5 videos playback speed

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, youtube

In Firefox you can control the playback speed of HTML5 videos by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and typing the following in the console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 1
```

Although this method is reasonably general (up to 4x with audio and up to 16x(?) without audio), it is somewhat cumbersome to do manually. It would be nice to have a shortcut and, moreover, a way to set a default value for all playbacks.

There are a couple of Firefox add-ons that seems to solve these issues (i.e. shortcut and default value):

- [Video Speed Controller](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/videospeed/)
- [Playback speed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/playback-speed/)
- [Video Speed Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-speed-changer/)
- [Faster Video](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/faster-video/)

However, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on_(Mozilla)#Security), there are some security risks associated with add-ons.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to solve the aforementioned issues without add-ons?
2. Are these add-ons safe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like it is here to promote a particular Firefox extension

Comment: @SirAdelaide It is somewhat weird to promote a particular add-on by emphasizing the security risks associated with it and even asking for other add-on recommendations.

Comment: sorry, just feeling particularly paranoid today. Particularly as the 'according to Wikipedia' bit raised red flags with me as the risks of running someone else's code should be obvious to pretty much everyone. The reduction in risk due to the code being available for others to test (its linked from the add-on page) is also real (though not foolproof), so the security angle seemed like a cover/diversion. Product recommendation requests are off topic. 5 questions at once makes the question too broad. Taken together these issues are why I voted to close.

Comment: This question is still off topic here, according to [the help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic): `it is not about … websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress`.

Comment: Just for the records: add-ons order based on google's search order.

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini This question isn't about a particular web service, but about Firefox's feature in general

Comment: "Are these add-ons safe?" needs more clarification.  Are they malware?  Do they conflict with other add-ons and cause problems?  Do they open exposure to exploits?  Are they safe relative to something else?  Might they damage files?  Without clarification of what you mean by safe, that part is too open-ended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can avoid using extensions with bookmarklets. A bookmarklet is a browser bookmark that doesn't actually open a webpage, but executes a piece of Javascript. Bookmarklets use the `javascript:` pseudoprotocol.

For example create a bookmark with this URL:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2})();
```

to set double playback speed. Create more bookmarks with adjusted `playbackRate` values you frequently use.

This is completely secure, because entire code executed by the browser is under your control.

Comment: Couldn't make it work with your code. Shouldn't it be like: `javascript:(function(){ document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate=4; })();`

Comment: @MarkMessa Honestly, I haven't tested it because I don't use Firefox. It's possible that the browser doesn't parse this assignment correctly and it has to be wrapped in parentheses or an IIFE as you did. If you can confirm that your version works, I'll update my answer.

Comment: _"it has to be wrapped in parentheses"_ I tried that before but it didn't worked.

Comment: _"If you can confirm that your version works, I'll update my answer."_ Indeed it worked.

Comment: whats the maximum speed?

Comment: Indeed the code in the response is missing a `}`. The proper working code is: `javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2})();`

Comment: @diogovk You're right, it's fixed now. Thanks!